# Google BigQuery clientid and fullvisitorid are not exactly the same when counting. Any one know why?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We thought clientid and fullvisitorid were one-to-one corresponding. However, the queries below show otherwise.

```
select count(*) ct_byfullvisitorid --121409
from
( Select  distinct fullvisitorid
  FROM `project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705`
) 

select count(*) ct_byclientid --121397
from
( Select  distinct clientid 
  FROM `project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705`
)
```

We were expecting the two queries to return exactly the same value, but that was not the case. So we thought we could use the following query to list the clientids that cause the difference

```
select * 
from
(
Select  clientid, fullvisitorid
  FROM `project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705`
) as a
where exists
(
Select  *
  FROM `project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705` s2
  where a.clientid = s2.clientid and a.fullvisitorid != s2.fullvisitorid
)
```

We were wrong again -- this SQL statement returned zero record.

Has anyone run into the same problem? Can anyone explain the situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
select fullvisitorid, count(distinct clientid) as numclients
from project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705
group by fullvisitorid
having count(distinct clientid) <> 1;
```

and

```
select clientid, count(distinct fullvisitorid) as numvisitors
from project.datasouce.ga_sessions_20180705
group by clientid
having count(distinct fullvisitorid) <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the clientID can be null. This was totally not expected. Thanks Gordon for the SQL.